# PHP Curl 'GET' returning NULL

Tags: php, curl, get

Firstly...to pre-empt....yes I have written simple Curl requests in PHP before and managed to get the expected data back...secondly yes there are plenty of similar questions out there, but I still can't get this to work!

Here is the code:

```
<?php

//Set Variables
$url = "https://coinroom.com/api/availableCurrencies";
$headers = array('accept: application/json');

//Initialise Session
$cSession = curl_init(); 

//Apply Variables
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER,$headers); 

//Execute
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

//Close Curl
curl_close($cSession);

//Var Dump
var_dump($result);


?>
```

This returns NULL, however what it should return is shown here:

https://coinroom.com/public-api

Is there actually anything wrong with my code, or could it be something odd with the api?

Answer (score 0):

Don't show the headers on the Response so you can json decode the result

```
<?php

//Set Variables
$url = "https://coinroom.com/api/availableCurrencies";
$headers = array('accept: application/json');

//Initialise Session
$cSession = curl_init(); 

//Apply Variables
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);


//Execute
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

//Close Curl
curl_close($cSession);

//Var Dump
var_dump($result);


?>
```

Comment: already tried that, it doesn't seem to make any difference :-(

Comment: Copy past the code and check again it works , and don't forget to replace the $ch by $cSession on line 12

Comment: I had missed the $ch on line 12! But even copy pasting that code directly from here, it still returns Null :-(

Answer (score 0):

you only comment line `$headers = array('accept: application/json');` and change `$ch` in line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");` into `$cSession`

Comment: Do you sure have installed php-curl ?

Comment: I believe its installed correctly on the basis that the same code (minus the GET and Headers bit) works for other websites.

Thats why I was wondering if the problem is with one of those two lines or with the api itself (I listed the website, which has a very limited support page, just in case I'm missing something that someone more astute may spot)!